# How to destroy expanded elements

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, dynamic

I am using PHP, mySQL and JQuery Mobile to dynamically create a question and answer routine.  Based on the users answer a set of new questions can be generated.  Everything is working great except, I can not figure out how to destroy an expanded element.  If the user goes down a path of questions and then decided to change his mind and goes back up anywhere in the chain of questions, I want the answers that he has already entered to be destroyed.  The JQuery Mobile collapsible is working great, but if the user changes his mind again and goes back down the first path, all of the original answers remain.

I have been working this for several hours, searching the internet for solutions.  Please let me know if I have not accurately explained my issues and will attempt to provide more detail

Comment: What did you try by yourself?

Comment: Not sure you are being productive, do you have an answer?  As I mentioned, I have spent several hours searching for an answer.  I've come here in hopes of finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.  I was unable to find a way to clear the previously expanded items.  So I developed my own routine to load current value(or null)to each answer within the collapsible div